# Inputting different passwords always redirects to the HTML page of the first password

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a password system, in which for specific password, it redirects to a custom web-page, Like a *support-type* system

But whenever I type the password: `tanishq1e01`, or `tanishq1e02`, it always returns the webpage for
`tanishq1e02` webpage. Why?

I expected that it would output a different webpage for each password, but it doesn't work!

```js
var ff;
let tanishq1e01 = "tanishq1e01";
let tanishq1e02 = "tanishq1e02"
ff = prompt("Enter Given Password By Prattay: ");
if (ff == tanishq1e01) {
  window.location.href = "suppstsasd/tanishq1e01suppasd.html";
} else if (ff = tanishq1e02) {
  window.location.href = "suppstsasd/tanishq1e02suppasd.html";
} else {
  confirm("Not Right Password! Refreshing...");
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Typo: You have a `=` instead of `==` in the second test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `=` assignment instead of `==` or `===` compare in the second test.

Here is a more elegant way, where it is easier to add locations

This is assuming you want to use such insecure way to load pages.

```js
const locations = {
  "tanishq1e01": "suppstsasd/tanishq1e01suppasd.html",
  "tanishq1e02": "suppstsasd/tanishq1e02suppasd.html"
}
let ff = prompt("Enter Given Password By Prattay: ");
let loc = locations[ff];
if (!loc) {
  alert("Not Right Password! Refreshing...");
  window.location.reload();
}
else {
  console.log("Going to", loc);
  window.location.href = loc;
}
```

Comment: Thx! I Really Have Been Struggling With this One!

Comment: You Are Welcome But PLEASE Do Not Write Like This! It is REALLY irritating to read. It is not cool looking

Comment: Ok! I Will See The Guidelines